# Script to run sets of commands

Tags: command-line

I would like to run fdisk and automatically do a particular command, like p (print)

**installation.sh:**

```
fdisk /dev/sdc1
```

I don't know how to give the process input to the programm.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use  crontab

```
crontab -e
```

crontab tool in linux is used to run script automatically.

you have to write `MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD your_script` in crontab shell than you script will run automatically.

suppose if min=1 and remaining things are * than your script will run in every 1 min.

For more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron